# Hide drop down menu title when clicking on menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

How do I hide the drop down menu title? My code looks like this:

```
<select id="menu1" name="Borgerskaber efter erhverv">
    <option id="title">Digitale borgerskaber 1679-1910</option>
    <option value="https://online.flippingbook.com/view/956512/">Register til borgerskabsprotokol 1679-1887</option>
    <option value="https://online.flippingbook.com/view/707957/">Borgerskabsprotokol 1679-1887</option>
    <option value="https://online.flippingbook.com/view/208653/">Borgerskabsprotokol 1869-1910</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var urlmenu = document.getElementById('menu1'),


    title = document.getElementById('title');

    urlmenu.onchange = function() {


    if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].id != "title") {


    window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value );
        }

    }; 
</script>
```

Comment: not clear can u be a bit more specific?

Comment: The fields inside the dropdown menu (with the tag option) should list the options of the menu. If you want to display a title (label) you can do it outside the menu.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the first option in the drop down list disabled use **'selected disabled'**
Use the following instead:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <select id="menu1" name="Borgerskaber_efter_erhverv">
    <option id="title" selected disabled>Digitale borgerskaber 1679-1910</option>
    <option value="https://online.flippingbook.com/view/956512/">Register til borgerskabsprotokol 1679-1887</option>
    <option value="https://online.flippingbook.com/view/707957/">Borgerskabsprotokol 1679-1887</option>
    <option value="https://online.flippingbook.com/view/208653/">Borgerskabsprotokol 1869-1910</option>
  </select>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var urlmenu = document.getElementById('menu1'),


      title = document.getElementById('title');

    urlmenu.onchange = function() {


      if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].id != "title") {


        window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
      }

    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```